# Toggle not showing the data

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a problem with the toggling to tabs here when I try to toggle to next tab (i.e. home tab to profile tab), I cannot see the content of the profile tab. Instead I just see blank space. Why I cannot he the content of that section? What is the mistake?

```js
// get the elements for the tabs
var aboutTab = document.getElementById("home-tab");
var timelineTab = document.getElementById("profile-tab");

// get the elements for the content sections
var aboutSection = document.getElementById("home");
var timelineSection = document.getElementById("profile");

// add click event listeners to the tabs
aboutTab.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // remove the "active" class from the timeline tab
  timelineTab.classList.remove("active");
  // add the "active" class to the about tab
  aboutTab.classList.add("active");

  // hide the timeline section
  timelineSection.style.display = "none";
  // show the about section
  aboutSection.style.display = "block";
});

timelineTab.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // remove the "active" class from the about tab
  aboutTab.classList.remove("active");
  // add the "active" class to the timeline tab
  timelineTab.classList.add("active");

  // hide the about section
  aboutSection.style.display = "none";
  // show the timeline section
  timelineSection.style.display = "block";
});
```

```css
body {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #3931af, #00c6ff);
}

.emp-profile {
  padding: 3%;
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  background: #fff;
}

.profile-img {
  text-align: center;
}

.profile-img img {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
}

.profile-img .file {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: -20%;
  width: 70%;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  background: #212529b8;
}

.profile-img .file input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.profile-head h5 {
  color: #333;
}

.profile-head h6 {
  color: #0062cc;
}

.profile-edit-btn {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  width: 70%;
  padding: 2%;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #6c757d;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.proile-rating {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #818182;
  margin-top: 5%;
}

.proile-rating span {
  color: #495057;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.profile-head .nav-tabs {
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.profile-head .nav-tabs .nav-link {
  font-weight: 600;
  border: none;
}

.profile-head .nav-tabs .nav-link.active {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #0062cc;
}

.profile-work {
  padding: 14%;
  margin-top: -15%;
}

.profile-work p {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #818182;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.profile-work a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #495057;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.profile-work ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.profile-tab label {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.profile-tab p {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #0062cc;
}

.tab-content .tab-pane {
  display: none;
}

.tab-content .tab-pane.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>



<div class="container emp-profile">
  <form method="post">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="profile-img">
          <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS52y5aInsxSm31CvHOFHWujqUx_wWTS9iM6s7BAm21oEN_RiGoog" alt="" />
          <div class="file btn btn-lg btn-primary">
            Change Photo
            <input type="file" name="file" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="profile-head">
          <h5>
            Kshiti Ghelani
          </h5>
          <h6>
            Web Developer and Designer
          </h6>
          <p class="proile-rating">RANKINGS : <span>8/10</span></p>
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Timeline</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="submit" class="profile-edit-btn" name="btnAddMore" value="Edit Profile" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="profile-work">
          <p>WORK LINK</p>
          <a href="">Website Link</a><br/>
          <a href="">Bootsnipp Profile</a><br/>
          <a href="">Bootply Profile</a>
          <p>SKILLS</p>
          <a href="">Web Designer</a><br/>
          <a href="">Web Developer</a><br/>
          <a href="">WordPress</a><br/>
          <a href="">WooCommerce</a><br/>
          <a href="">PHP, .Net</a><br/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="tab-content profile-tab" id="myTabContent">
          <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>User Id</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <p>Kshiti123</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>Name</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <p>Kshiti Ghelani</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>Email</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <p>kshitighelani@gmail.com</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>Phone</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <p>123 456 7890</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>Profession</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <p>Web Developer and Designer</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>Experience</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <p>Expert</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>Hourly Rate</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <p>10$/hr</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>Total Projects</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <p>230</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>English Level</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <p>Expert</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>Availability</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <p>6 months</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <label>Your Bio</label><br/>
                <p>Your detail description</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you including both bootstrap 4 and 5 in your code?

Comment: Could be because of having both the versions of bootstrap...

Comment: @j08691 @
Praveen Kumar Purushothaman I tried using bootstrap 4 and it was not working. So tried 5...But still not working...I have tried both seperately too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your code with the one below. Please note the comment I've added "// I HAVE ADDED THIS PART"

```
// add click event listeners to the tabs
      aboutTab.addEventListener("click", function() {
        // remove the "active" class from the timeline tab
        timelineTab.classList.remove("active");
        // add the "active" class to the about tab
        aboutTab.classList.add("active");
      
        // hide the timeline section
        timelineSection.style.display = "none";

        // show the about section
        aboutSection.style.display = "block";

    
        // I HAVE ADDED THIS PART
        timelineSection.classList.remove("show");
        aboutSection.classList.add("show");
      });
      
      timelineTab.addEventListener("click", function() {
        // remove the "active" class from the about tab
        aboutTab.classList.remove("active");
        // add the "active" class to the timeline tab
        timelineTab.classList.add("active");
      
        // hide the about section
        aboutSection.style.display = "none";
        aboutSection.classList.remove("show");
        // show the timeline section
        timelineSection.style.display = "block";
        

        // I HAVE ADDED THIS PART
        timelineSection.classList.add("show");
        aboutSection.classList.remove("show");
      });
```

- 

The reason why it's not showing is because of the class added to the profile div element where it has a classname `show` which creates an opacity of `0`. It's there but it's not visible.